# Binding Textblock Style/Converter

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderType}"/>
```

OrderType is a string can potentially be A,B,C,D.  But I want the textblock to display YES if (A or B) and NO if (C or D), but want the foreground color to be Green if A, Blue if B, Yellow if C, Red if D.  What would be the best way to do this?  I'm a little confused if I use a converter, what the style trigger should bind to or if there is a better approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do this with Triggers only, there's a bit of redundancy though:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderType}" Value="A">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="YES" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderType}" Value="B">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="YES" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderType}" Value="C">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="NO" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding OrderType}" Value="D">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="NO" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use an IValueConverter for this purpose:

```
public class OrderTypeToYesNoConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            if(value != null)
            {
                 string val = value.ToString();
                 if(val == "A" || val == "B")
                    return "YES"; 
            }
            return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### XAML

```
<Window
    ..
    ..
    xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:NameSpace;assembly=Assembly">
<Window.Resources>
    <converters:OrderTypeToYesNoConverter x:Key="OrderTypeToYesNoConverter"/> 
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding OrderType, Converter="{StaticResource OrderTypeToYesNoConverter}"/>
```

Comment: @H.B. Fine, object it, but tell us why =) The converter approach is very reusable, which is why I tend to advise to use them instead of triggers.

Comment: Converters are obviously for conversions, like boolean to visibility. For something like this where there are just multiple cases (like a switch) a converter seems like abuse to me.

Comment: @H.B. I've just shown an example, but you can make them more generic, by using the "parameter" parameter. I've seen people make their own custom script language through it, and it reduces the XAML code a lot. You also get a better shot at debugging!

Comment: There is no intrinsic value in reducing XAML, script languages are imperative, which goes completely against what XAML is all about: declarative markup.

Comment: @H.B.I'm obviously not talking about a massive script language above XAML. But a converter generic enough so that you can do "A | B => YES, C | D => NO" saves 18 lines in the XAML you provided, and doesn't reinvent WPF.

Comment: i dont think the converter really helps, because i need to do coloring as well

Comment: You'd have had to make 2 converters.